# delete duplicate rows from table row number partition by

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates, sql-delete, window-functions

delete duplicates per `com_id`:

I have to write a generic `DELETE` that will remove vald records to the end of the world (`vald_to = 9999-01-01`) 
if:

- tar_id = -1
- vald_from = 0001-01-01
- there is another record for this com_id with vald_to = 9999-01-01

The query is:

```
  delete from C
  where (COM_ID, VALD_TO) in
   (
    select 
    COM_ID,
    VALD_TO,
    row_number()
        over 
        (partition by COM_IDorder by VALD_TO DESC) dup
     from C
        where 
    tar_id=-1
        and
    vald_from = 0001-01-01
        and
    dup > 1
    );
```

The script removes all records for the com_id

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: `vald_from = 0001-01-01` ... do you literally have this in your query?

Comment: The date type does not matter

Answer (score 0):

You could use rowid, this `delete` worked for me:

```
delete from c
  where rowid in (
    select rwd 
      from (
        select rowid rwd, 
               row_number() over (partition by com_id order by null) dup
          from c
          where tar_id = -1 
            and vald_from = date '0001-01-01'
            and vald_to   = date '9999-01-01' )
      where dup > 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you consider a duplicate you want removed. So just guessing: You are considering a record a duplicate, when its range is covered by another record. E.g.:

```
COM_ID   vald_from    vald_to
123      0001-01-01   9999-01-01
123      0001-01-01   2017-01-01
```

The second record is superfluous, because its range is only part of the larger range of the first record. But the same would be true for:

```
COM_ID   vald_from    vald_to
123      2016-01-01   2017-01-01
123      2016-02-01   2016-03-01
```

Again, the second record's range is only part of the first one's.

A query to remove those superfluous records would be:

```
delete from c
where exists
(
  select *
  from c other
  where other.com_id = c.com_id
  and other.vald_from <= c.vald_from
  and other.vald_to >= c.vald_to
  and other.rowid <> c.rowid
)
and tar_id = -1;
```

I don't know, whether you want `tar_id = -1` inside the subquery, too. And maybe you still want to restrict this somehow to dates `date '0001-01-01'` and `date '9999-01-01'`. If so, adjust the statement accordingly.

Comment: VALD_FROM          VALD_TO                   TAR_ID         COM_ID
2016-04-13         9999-01-01                   468                  267 
2017-11-07         9999-01-01                   569                  343
2017-11-07         9999-01-01                  1 355                267 
0001-01-01          9999-01-01                    -1                  343

Comment: I have no idea what your "comment" is supposed to mean. Does my query work for you? If not, in what way is it different from what you want?